# Termination Regulator for DDR4

Tags: voltage-regulator, memory, termination, ddr4

I went through a previous Industrial PC Motherboard design in my company where Ritchtek [RT9045](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1yvo51cpj1yri0/DS9045-02-2.pdf?dl=0) was used for DDR4 design. it's clearly recommended tat this device is ideal for DDRII/DDRIII in the features.

I'm designing a PC motherboard which uses Intel Tiger Lake UP3 CPU. and I was wondering if I can use this device for my DDR4 SODIMMs.

what are the parameters that I should consider that could affect my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To back up a bit, the termination regulator exists to make sure the termination voltage (VTT) is half the supply voltage (VDDQ). The biggest concern I would have is the VTT tolerance on your new DDR4 parts. For the first round of prototypes, I would also put a current sensing resistor to make sure this part isn't close to its design maximum trying to sink current during regulation.